# Why are String parameters always null in a Spring Boot 1.5 @Controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, controller

I migrated a Spring 4.1 application (running I JBoss) to SpringBoot 1.5 (Spring 4.3.7), and after that, all our MVC Controllers with String parameters always receive null values when called.

The only way I could get the parameter value set was to replace String with StringBuilder.

An example, not working anymore:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateTime", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateTime(@RequestParam(value="time") String time) {
  // time is null in SpringBoot
}
```

Working (StringBuffer instead of String:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateTime", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateTime(@RequestParam(value="time") StringBuffer time) {
  // time has expected value
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="updateTime" action="updateTime.html" method="post">
    Time: <input type="text" name="time" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm" value="${time}"/> <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="   Update   "/>
</form>
```

Even when String parameters in the controller are compounded into a request object I get this behaviour.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Why don't you go for a never version than SpringBoot 1.5. ?

Comment: @LahiruWijesekara: Will do, took a medium step to avoid too many issues with spring-security and ws-security

Answer (score 2):

**INFO** : Spring Works with HTML name attributes.
You should have the same name and RequestParam value.
Note : in the HTML form action it's better to have  the same as the RequestMapping value also.
Try this :

```
<form name="updateTime" action="/updateTime" method="post">
    Time: <input type="text" name="time" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm" value="${time}"/> <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="   Update   "/>
</form>
```

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateTime", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateTime(@RequestParam(value="time") String time) {
  // time is null in SpringBoot
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, I edited the code to translate to english, and just forgot one place. They do have the same name.